# Can I update an endorsement policy in Hyperledger Fabric using node sdk?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I am setting the endorsement policy while instantiating chaincode, I wanted to know if I can update the endorsement policy at a later stage using node sdk because when new organizations are added to the channel, I want them to also be part of the endorsement policy. Currently the workaround we are doing is upgrading the chaincode to a new version, install it on all peers again, and then change the endorsement policy while upgrading. It doesn't feel like the right way to do it though. Any directions in this regard will greatly help!

Comment: Your "workaround" is the correct way to do it, by using https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-1.4/Client.html#installChaincode and https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-1.4/Channel.html#sendUpgradeProposal__anchor.

Comment: Ah, alright. I was wondering if this really is the correct way to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually the right solution to do that in fabric release-1.4 .

The endorsement policy is unlike the channel configuration which you may update it by using the delta-envelope as @kekomal says. You can update channel config with 
new Orgs, new peers and CRLs, but not the chaincode policies.

The endorsement policy is being settled when exactly the chaincode is instantiated, which means it is in the chaincode-lifecycle, individually from the channel configuration.

Although the whole new chaincode-lifecycle came out with fabric release-2.1（since 2.0） is a totally different story, there might be a chance that you won't need to upgrade the chaincode everytime.

> In addition to the specifying an endorsement policy from the CLI or SDK, a chaincode can also use policies in the channel configuration as endorsement policies. You can use the `–channel-config-policy`flag to select a channel policy with format used by the channel configuration and by ACLs.

[see here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.1/endorsement-policies.html#setting-chaincode-level-endorsement-policies)

Everytime you brought a new org to your network, you will need to update the channel config. Since the chaincode could use the same policy the channel did, you might as well give the new lifecycle a shot.

I have not tried it so far since I am only offering some of my thoughts here. Let me know if this works pls.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey, thanks David. Currently, I might not be able to try out the new lifecycle, but will certainly give it a shot like you suggested as soon as I can! Will update the same here.